# Get result with list

Tags: list, scheme

#### ;How to get the value of 'a' in 'b'?

*;Not want to assign the letter 'a' in 'b' want the value contained in 'a'*

```
(define a 5)
(define c '(a c))
(define b (car c))
(display b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define a 5)
(define c (list a 'c))
(define b (car c))
(display b)
```

`'` is equivalent to the `quote` procedure. So `'(a c)` => `(list 'a 'c)`

See: http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Quoting.html#Quoting

Or, using your original code, are you asking how you would `(eval b (the-environment))`?

Comment: yes I know this but I want to know how I get in on list one symbol and get of your variable corresponding. example: Variable a your value is 5 then when b get symbol a i want the value of a. beacase i define a are variable.

Comment: Are you saying you would want to `(eval b (the-environment))`?

Comment: If you have the symbol `'a`, to get the value of the variable `a` from it, you must use `eval` (`(eval 'a (the-environment)) => 5`). I'm sorry if this is not your question, I am having a hard time understanding.

Comment: So to get that value in b, you could `(define b (eval (car c) (the-environment)))`

Comment: and so just that I'm not understand what exactly is (the-environment).

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Environments.html#Environments

An environment basically contains bindings (for variables/procedures and their values) and a parent environment

Comment: I don't understand. You would like to see an example of (the-environment)? I've shown that you can use it in eval. Using it in eval causes eval to look for the symbol defined in the first argument in the environment given in the second argument. If it finds the symbol in that environment, the value is returned. Remember, an evironment is just a collection of bindings. For instance, think of it like a map: [a = 2, b = 7, some-variable = 8 ...]